# Adding timezone offset in the datetime in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone-offset

Would like to convert timestamp stored in SQL to a specific timezone.

SQL Query to offset created_at time by -33000

```
select cast(created_at - 33000 as date) from table_name
```

The query is working fine but it's giving NULL for timestamp `2019-11-14 02:52:31`.

Any hints is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**SQL SERVER:**

Your query will cause some ***explicit conversion error***. So you have to convert it into proper `Datetime`, and then try you query.

```
select cast(CAST('2019-11-14 02:52:31' AS DATETIME) - 33000 as date)
```

**MySQL**

You have to use `DATEADD` function.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2019-11-14 02:52:31', INTERVAL -330 MINUTE);
```

The output will be `2019-11-13 21:22:31`

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Receiving same result.

Comment: @Ajay, Are you using `SQL SERVER` or something else?

Comment: We are using MySQL 5.7.22-log.

Comment: @Ajay, Give some sample data from the table, and show me the expected output you want.

Comment: For Input `2019-11-14 02:52:31`, Expected Output:- `2019-11-13 11:22:31`. when using offset as -330.

Comment: @Ajay, Try my Updated answer.